# Cloud config and SpEL in @Value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I met a issue,I try to listen to EnvironmentChangeEvent and re-init some configuration.

While i found that @Value annotation with SpEL is not working, but plain @Value annotation is OK:

```
@Component
public class ConsumeService {

    @Autowired
    ConsumeConfig consumeConfig;

 @EventListener(EnvironmentChangeEvent.class)
    void onEnvChange() {
     log.debug("{}",consumeConfig);

//when i print here, i get only consumeDesc, but cardList is an empty List.
    }
}



@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class ConsumeConfig {

    @Value("${consume.desc}")
    private String consumeDesc;

    @Value("#{'${api.server.round.card}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> cardList;
}
```

**Question:**

Is this issue related with lifecycle of SpEL? It seems that, the value of SpEL is not yet parsed.

Comment: What do you mean saying "@Value annotation with SpEL is not working"? Are you getting an Exception, null or an empty list? Can you, please, provide here `api.server.round.card` exact values you're trying to parse.

Comment: Something else must be wrong here. SpEL works fine with either List or Array.

Comment: When i mean not working, i got an empty list. I have post an issue to the project github repository, and got answer: not supporting SpEL.

Answer (score 0):

The split should return an array of String, not a list. Try this:

```
@Value("#{'${api.server.round.card}'.split(',')}")
private String[] cardList;
```